# Implement member function more than once

Tags: c++

For example you have such situation:

1)Header file with some class definition that contain some member function (def.h).

2)That header is included into .cpp files with the same name that resides in a separate folders.

3)That .cpp files impements same function from def.h but in different way.

3)Then we include that header into some main.cpp and call function with multiple impementation and compile that whole project.

Question: will it compile without errors? What function implementation will be chosen?

Comment: You've marked this as c++, is it a standard c function or a function / method of a class ?

Comment: @SPlatten it doesn't matter which

Comment: @SPlatten By "member function" I means - method of a class.

Comment: why don't you implement your 4 points and see if it compiles or not?

Comment: @mfnx C++ is not ameanable to the scientific method, because of undefined behaviour

Comment: @mfnx Done that. It depends from compiler (linker). Some of them gives error and refuse to launch program. Some of them works fine. So wich one of the compilers behaves well?

Comment: They all behave well

Comment: @Caleth So in this case, I think, it's depends from compiler engineers taste. Is it true?

Comment: Identifying violations is a difficult problem, keeping in mind that *not* re-compiling code that you don't have to is a desirable characteristic of a build system.

Comment: @Caleth, of course it matters because a c++ class methods can be overloaded so duplicate function names are permitted, you overload a standard c function.

Comment: @SPlatten you absolutely *can* overload a free function. e.g. [std::abs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs). But that isn't what we are talking about. We are talking about `class Foo { void bar(); };` in def.h, and then `void Foo::bar() { std::cout << "1"; }` in def1.cpp and `void Foo::bar() { std::cout << "2"; }` in def2.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a function in two separate places violates [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

> One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). **The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined.**

To have well-defined behavior, you should either:

- Link just one of the definitions in the final program
- Use [overloads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) instead
- Use polymorphism/inheritance instead

Comment: So this valid and will not lead to compile or link errors?

Comment: @oleg It is not valid, but is not required to cause compile or link errors.

Comment: @oleg C++ doesn't require or forbid *anything* in this case. It can build, it can fail to build. If it builds your whole program can do different things on tuesdays

Comment: @oleg you're trying to do is what are templates are meant to.  regardless or what file is definition is in, it's legal only to have one definition for a function, member or not.  Member function of different instances of template will have different definitions though.